Is it possible to setup a sub/second domain for free/testing?
I have a free Azure account. I have setup an app service with an application and can see my website using x.azurewebsites.net
I need to trial one more test with the third party component im working with, therefore im trying to create a sub-domain or have two test domains pointing to the same instance of my app (the third-party tool would route the incoming request to the appropriate areas).
Is it possible for me to have two URLs in this manner on Azure just for testing? I tried but all the buttons and options didnt allow me to do this so i dont know for sure if this is down to the type of account i have or if i need to upgrade, or even this is not supported by Azure provided domains so i have to setup a domain and have the DNS etc configured?
I was hoping i could do this via Azure and if it works then great rather than having to purchase domains to test the routing.
I read Azure articles which lead me to options i dont have, other menus dont exist or i get a 404 when clicking links to get to certain pages where i could try and attempt.

AFAIK,yes you need to add DNS Configuration and add CName

@Harshitha is there any documentation i can review and follow?

You can check the option Custom Domain in Azure App Service.Iam trying from my end.Will let you know.

Refer this MSDoc once

Another option available is using DEployment slots

Have you checked the deployment slots?


Is it possible to setup a sub/second domain for free/testing?

You need to purchase a custom domain to configure DNS zone for Azure App Service.

In Azure App Service we have an option to purchase App Service Domain. But this option is not available for free/trial subscriptions.

Even MSdOC explains the same.

Free trial and credit based subscriptions are not eligible to create an App Service Domain.


I have tried to create a App Service Domain with free subscription but failed.



As you are using a free Subscription you may be having limited access to the available resources.


rather than having to purchase domains to test the routing.

Another option available to test the instance is to create a Deployment slot by cloning the Production slot.


A new Instance with same code and configurations will be created.



The newly created slot will run under the same App Service Plan with the unique URL (AppName-slotname.azurewebsites.net).

After testing you can swap the dev slot with production slot if any changes are done in the dev slot.




As your requirement is to test the existing instance incoming requests, AFAIK this will be the better option.


@KeithViking - Please check the updated solution
